# Non-Linear Regression for Parameter Estimation

Tags: statistics, laplace-transform, regression, nonlinear-system

I have a second order system, it's response to a step change can be expressed in the s-space as:

$$Y(s)=\frac{K_{2}e^{-\theta s}}{s(\tau_{1} s + 1)(\tau_{2} s + 1)}$$

Which can be inverse transformed to:
$$y(t)=K_{2}\Bigg(1-\frac{\tau_{1}e^{\frac{-(t+\theta)}{\tau_{1}}}-\tau_{2}e^{\frac{-(t+\theta)}{\tau_{2}}}}{\tau_{1}-\tau_{2}}\Bigg)$$

I have data points ($t,y(t)$), how can I use Gauss-Newton to estimate the parameters $\tau_{1} $, $\tau_{2} $ and $\theta$
.

Comment: what math tools to you have?

Comment: One possible approximation is: Assuming Y(s) is always positive. $\log Y(s) = \log K_2 - \theta s - \log s -\log \beta$ where $\beta = \tau^2s^2 + 2\zeta \tau s + 1$. You should be able to use linear regression to find $\theta$ and $\log \beta$. Then solve for $\tau, \zeta$ by setting $\tau^2 s^2 + 2\zeta\tau s + 1 = \beta$. If $Y(s)$ is not positive, then of course this is pointless.

Comment: @MrYouMath I have access to Matlab, Mathematica and Excel, I have most the popular Matlab packages from uni computers

Comment: @TenaliRaman Thanks, I'll look into that

Comment: @TenaliRaman Sorry, kind of a silly question but I have my results in the time domain, so y[output] and t[time], how can I bring them into the s domain for analysis?

Comment: @MathsIsHard I am not sure, what that would entail sorry. However, I found this in matlab [1]. So you don't have to do the silly approximation I suggested, and instead use this to fit your regression parameters.

[1] http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html

Comment: This resource might help you. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html

Comment: my data points are $(t,y(t))$ and $K_{2}$ is known, it is the gain of the system which I can calculate analytically. @mvw

Comment: @mvw my bad, just an engineering habit, sometimes it's easier to think of problems in the s domain

Comment: The general idea is to have a set of data points $(t_i, y_i=y(t_i))$ and a bunch of functions $y(t)=F(t, r, \theta, \zeta)$ and then fiddle with the parameters $r, \theta, \zeta$ to minimize some suitable distance $d((t_i, y_i), (t_i. F(t_i, r. \theta, \zeta))$. So we need $y(t)$ not $Y(s)$. Or somehow transform the $(t_i, y_i)$ into $(s_i, Y_i)$ and fit in $s$-space.

Comment: @mvw Ah, I edited my original post with y(t). Would the Gauss-Newton method be sufficient for my needs?

Answer (score 0):

The model being $$Y=\frac{Ke^{-\theta s}}{s(\tau^2s^2+2\zeta\tau s + 1)}$$ it is obvious that nonlinear regression is required. But this implies to have some réasonable estimates fo parameters $K,\theta,\tau,\zeta$.

To me, the first step would be to consider that $\theta$ is given a value. Now, rewrite the model as $$\frac {e^{-\theta s}}{s Y}=\frac {\tau^2}K s^2+\frac {2\zeta \tau}K s+\frac 1K$$ So, defining for each data point $$z_i=\frac {e^{-\theta s_i}}{s_i Y_i}$$ you have to fit the model $$z=a s^2+b s+c$$ which is simple. When you have obtained parameters $a,b,c$ from the linear regression, compute the predicted $Y$'s according to $$Y_i^{calc}=\frac{e^{-\theta s_i}}{s_i(as_i^2+bs_i+c)}$$ and $$SSQ(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^n\big(Y_i-Y_i^{calc}\big)^2$$ Now, run different values of $\theta$ and look for a point looking more or less as a minimum. At this point, you have all you estimates $$K=\frac 1c \qquad \tau=\sqrt{aK}\qquad \zeta=\frac{bK}{2\tau}$$

If parameter $K$ is imposed, the problem is simpler since the model can write $$\frac 1s\Big(\frac {Ke^{-\theta s}}{s Y}-1\Big)={\tau^2} s+ {2\zeta \tau}$$ Define $$z_i=\frac 1{s_i}\Big(\frac {Ke^{-\theta s_i}}{s_i Y_i}-1\Big)$$ and fit the model $$z=a s +b$$ and do the same as above.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, the issue is my data is in the time domain, can can I transform my experimental data into the a domain for analysis?

Comment: Sorry I meant s domain

Comment: Please see my updated original post

Answer (score 0):

$$y(t)=K_{2}\Bigg(1-\frac{\tau_{1}e^{\frac{-(t+\theta)}{\tau_{1}}}-\tau_{2}e^{\frac{-(t+\theta)}{\tau_{2}}}}{\tau_{1}-\tau_{2}}\Bigg)$$
Rewrited as :
$$y(t)=a+be^{pt}+ce^{qt} \quad \begin{cases}
a=K_2 \\
b=-K_2\frac{\tau_1 e^{-\theta/\tau_1}}{\tau_1-\tau_2} \\
c=-K_2\frac{\tau_2 e^{-\theta/\tau_2}}{\tau_1-\tau_2} \\ 
p=-\frac{1}{\tau_1} \\
q=-\frac{1}{\tau_2}
\end{cases}
$$
The approximates of $p$ and $q$ can be computed thanks to a straightforward method ( without initial guess and not iterative).

The principle of this unusual method is explained in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

An example is presented in full details, page 72, in case of $\quad y(t)=be^{pt}+ce^{qt}$

With $y(t)=a+be^{pt}+ce^{qt}$ ,  the calculus is exactly the same for the first part (up to equations $p_1=...$ , $q_1=...$ ).

Of course, with the parameter $a$ in addition, the computation of $a$ , $b$ , $c$ is slightly different : This is a classical linear regression with three parameters instead of two.